# Does a Force on the block $M_1$ in this diagram have an effect on the block $M_2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Suppose we have two blocks:

[image]

There is no friction. Does $F$ has the same effect on $M_2$?

Comment: The applied force $F$ does not affect M2. M2 is affected through friction/normal force by M1.

Comment: they have the same acceleration so F affects M2 but not directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no friction at all between the two masses, any force on the bottom one will just pull it right from under the one on top of it, which will subsequently fall straight down. It's as simple as that.